# Add new message to object that is indexed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

I've created a messenger that stores the last five messages from an api in an indexed object:

```
data: function() {
   return {
     messages: {  
         "0":{  
            "id":65,
            "body":"Hopefully last message",
         },
         "1":{  
            "id":64,
            "body":"Another message",
         },
         "2":{  
            "id":63,
            "body":"This work work?",
         },
         "3":{  
            "id":62,
            "body":"Yoo",
         },
         "4":{  
            "id":61,
            "body":"Hey again",
         }
      }
   }
},
```

I'm using socket.io to get the last message sent and what I would like to do is push the last message sent to the indexed objects `this.messages` and shift the index so the message received by the socket is the "0" indexed object.

```
mounted() {
   console.log("message mounted");

   let socket = io(`http://localhost:3000`);
   this.getOldMessages(this.conversationPath);

   socket.on('message', function (data) {

      data.message[0]

      //Shift data.message[0] into this.message object indexed as "0"

   }.bind(this));
},
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason that `this.messages` is not an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to treat `messages` pretty much like an array that you can unshift onto. So you convert it into an array, unshift onto it, and convert it back. This is the same answer as puddi gave, but it seems you had an issue with the order of messages his solution generated. I can't tell from your comment whether you *expect* it to do something different from ordinary array unshift, or whether his *does* something weird.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      messages: {
        "0": {
          "id": 65,
          "body": "Hopefully last message",
        },
        "1": {
          "id": 64,
          "body": "Another message",
        },
        "2": {
          "id": 63,
          "body": "This work work?",
        },
        "3": {
          "id": 62,
          "body": "Yoo",
        },
        "4": {
          "id": 61,
          "body": "Hey again",
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    unshift(message) {
      const arr = [];
      const result = {};

      // Like Object.keys, loop through keys of object
      Reflect.ownKeys(this.messages).forEach((k) => {
        // Assign to corresponding array element
        arr[k] = this.messages[k];
      });
      // Put the message on the front of the array
      arr.unshift(message);
      // Copy array values and indexes into result object
      arr.forEach((v, i) => {
        result[i] = v;
      });
      return result;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Put a new message on the front of messages
    console.log("message mounted");
    const newMessage = {
      id: 66,
      body: 'PS: I love you'
    };
    this.messages = this.unshift(newMessage);
    console.log("Messages:", JSON.stringify(this.messages));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for this. Could you throw some comments in your code. I'm kind of newer to JS development and unfamiliar to some of the functionality here.

Comment: Commented. See if I covered what you were looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// transform the object into a correctly indexed array
let messagesArr = Array.from(Object.keys(this.messages).sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) < parseInt(b)), i => this.messages[i]);

// from here, you can add the message pretty easily.
messagesArr.unshift(data.message[0]);

// finally, just transform it back into an object (if you really have to)
const temp = {};
messagesArr.forEach((value, index) => temp["" + index] = value);
this.messages = temp;
```

Comment: Sorry I marked it as the answer before I noticed a flaw. The problem is  that all though the last message sent takes a zero index it changes the index of all the other messages in the wrong way. So if I have a bunch of messages from the least message to first message 3, message 2, message 1 if I recieve message 4 the order changes to message 4, message 1, message 2, message 3. Sorry for marking your reply early.